# .NET Hangfire.PostgreSql Could not load type 'Npgsql.TypeMapping.NpgsqlTypeMapping

Tags: .net, postgresql, docker, hangfire

I'm trying to implement Hangfire for recurring job but got trouble with PostgreSQL. The application uses .NET + PostgreSQL with docker. Since this is my first time using Hangfire, I tested it on a temp application using MSSQL and everything was perfect.

For my dockerized application with PosthgreSQL, I used this guide https://worldwildweb.dev/getting-started-with-hangfire-on-asp-net-core-and-postgresql-on-docker/ but when I'm trying to fetch data from the database I get this error:

[image]

Not only I get this error but before the installation of Hangfire.PostgreSql Nuget every call in database was Ok, I could fetch data.

This is the Startup.cs -> ConfigureServices & Configure

[image]

[image]

If I remove the Nuget Hangfire.PostgreSql then every call in database will be ok, but in order for Hangfire to work the package is needed. The connection string is ok but I can't find a way to resolve this problem.

Comment: Have you checked that all package related to Pgsql (including hangfire and ef ) are aligned ? (seems like 6.0.4)
Also,you should check the dll version in your docker image

Comment: @jbl It seems like that the hangfire version for postgres was targeting .net 6 and out project's version is .net 5, took me much time to find out why, this and google translate helped me too when I saw your comment: https://ddeevv.com/question/elsa-workflows-elsa-core-2544.html

Comment: Nice ! You should summarize your findings in an answer tobyour on question.

Answer (score 0):

Package contributor here.

In late 2021 we noticed that .NET 5 would [only support Npgsql 5 (and EF provider)](https://github.com/npgsql/efcore.pg/issues/2141). We've introduced a separate package for people who are stuck on .NET 5: [Hangfire.PostgreSql.Npgsql5](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Hangfire.PostgreSql.Npgsql5).

If someone stumbles upon this, keep that in mind. Functionally it's the same package, simply with a reference to Npgsql 5 instead of 6 (or latest, depending on when you read the post).

At the time of this answer, the package is not switched to Npgsql 7. We want to see whether we need to do something similar with v6 too.